# Asymptotic Expansion Method for Pricing American Option

Tags: partial-differential-equations, asymptotics, stochastic-calculus, finance

In [this Article](http://www.economia.uniroma2.it/conference/Public/1/Paper/84.pdf) I faced with Asymptotic Expansion method for pricing American option. the price $P(S,t)$ of this option satisfies the partial differential equation (PDE): 
$${{P}_{t}}+(r-\delta )S{{P}_{S}}+\frac{1}{2}{{\sigma }^{2}}{{S}^{2}}{{P}_{SS}}-rP=0$$
with boundary conditions:

$\begin{align}
  & P(\infty ,t)=0,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,P(S,T)=\max \left( K-S,0 \right) \\ 
 & P\left( \bar{S}\left( T-t \right),t \right)=\max \left( K-\bar{S}\left( T-t \right),0 \right),\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,{{P}_{S}}\left( \bar{S}\left( T-t \right),t \right)=-1 \\ 
\end{align}$

Here, $\bar S(T-t)$ is the early exercise price, which  depends on the option time-to-maturity $\tau =T-t$. then the author mention that To derive proper asymptotic expansions, We rewrite PDE in terms of $(\theta , \tau )$ instead of $(S,t)$. Using the definition of $\theta =\frac{\ln \left( K/S \right)}{\sigma \sqrt{\tau }}$ and setting $P\left( \theta ,\tau  \right)=P\left( K{{e}^{-\sigma \theta \sqrt{\tau }}},T-\tau  \right)$ ,then  We
obtain:
$$\theta {{P}_{\theta }}+{{P}_{\theta \theta }}+\frac{1}{\sigma }[{{\sigma }^{2}}+2(\delta -r)]{{P}_{\theta }}\sqrt{\tau }-2({{P}_{\tau }}+rP)\tau =0$$

and satisfying boundary conditions in the form

$\begin{align}
& P(-\infty ,\tau )=0 \\
& P\left( y,\tau  \right)=K\max \left( 1-{{e}^{-\sigma y\sqrt{\tau }}},0 \right)=K\left( 1-{{e}^{-\sigma y\sqrt{\tau }}} \right) \\
\end{align}$

and which has regular asymptotics near maturity of the form

$$P\left( \theta ,\tau  \right)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty }{{{P}_{n}}\left( \theta  \right){{\tau }^{n/2}}}$$

*Now I have 2 questions* that any recommendations/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**First: Why Change of variables makes the PDE proper than it was ?**

**Second: How We can obtain the form of regular asymptotics near maturity ?**